# use python output in other software

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I have coded the endless loop which gives me a string every 2 seconds. Now, I have to use the strings coming every 2 seconds to trigger a video player software (Content management where videos can be played with a playlist). This more like an integration of the video media player and python.

For example, There are 10 videos saved in the media player and every video should be played once the player received the triggered from python.

Is it possible to trigger the media software to play video using the python output key? If yes then please advise me the procedure.

Note: the media player have many interfaces. 
Is there something I shall check in media player?

I am looking forward to seeing the positive response on my query. Thanks in advance

Best Regards,

Comment: Why don't you start the player from your Python code? If you don't want to do that, then Python is not really relevant to the question, and you need something to monitor the file that you are writing to.

Comment: *What* media player software? For some, you may be able to launch instances with `subprocess.Popen` and the instance coalescence rules will build the playlist, but we'd need to know what media player you're using.

Comment: Hi  @ShadowRanger , Thanks for your reply. I use content management software KOMPAS (https://www.kompas-software.de/de/Produkte/kompas_-_Digital_Signage_Software). I generate every 2 seconds a string keyword and want to trigger a particular content(Video playlist) in the given software.